# renameTo() not working on uploaded image : cos-MutipartRequest

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, file-upload, multipartform-data, file-rename

I am trying to get an image uploaded by user, store it in a folder(for which I am providing absolute path), store the path in database(Relative path) abd later use the path from database todisplay the image.

I am using cos-MultipartRequest jar file for this.

I don't want to have spaces in the file name(Since the image with spaces in name is not displayed by `<img>`)

The code I have written is:

```
String pathUPLOAD="D:/AdvJava/proimp/WebContent/images/default";
String pathDB="images/default";
MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,pathUPLOAD);
String file=m.getFilesystemName("file").replaceAll("\\s+",""); //to remove spaces
m.getFile("file").renameTo(new File(pathDB+file)); // to rename the uploaded file without whitespaces
//(tried this earlier)  m.getFile("file").renameTo(new File(file));
```

the path I am inserting in DB is: `pathDB+"/"+file`

The upload works fine and later the images are also displayed for those which don't have spaces in name.

But for those having spaces, the path stored in DB is the way I want, but the image uploaded in the specified directory does not has any changes in its name and therefore the place where images are to be displayed shows **a missing image**.

Any suggestions?